Definition of the Chern character
I encountered the definition of Chern character in Yuri Manin - Lectures on the K-functor in algebraic geometry and I cannot clarify these misconceptions from brief explanation, so I would like to ask some questions.
Let $X$ be a (regular) scheme and $\mathcal{E}$ be a locally free sheaf of rank $r$ on it. I have no problem with the definitions of Chern class or Chern polynomial using the $\gamma$-filtration of $K(X)$. They are defined by $c_i(\mathcal{E})=\gamma^i(cl(\mathcal{E})-rk(\mathcal{E})) \mod F^{i+1}K(X)$ which has the value in $G^iK(X)$, and $c_t(\mathcal{E})=1+\sum_{i=1}^\infty c_i(\mathcal{E})t^i$ which can be extended to a group homomorphism $c_t:K(X)\to 1+\oplus_{i=1}^\infty G^iK(X)t^i$. Now the Chern character $ch(\mathcal{E})\in GK(X)\otimes \mathbb{Q}$ is defined by $ch(\mathcal{E}) = \sum e^{a_i(\mathcal{E})}$, where $a_i(\mathcal{E})$ is obtained from the identity $c_t(\mathcal{E}) = \prod_{i=1}^r (1+a_i(\mathcal{E})t)$.
First question is that why $c_t$ splits into linear factors; I obviously tried to use the splitting principle. If we write $e = l + f$ in $K(\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E}))$ where $e = cl(\mathcal{E})$ and $l = cl(\mathcal{O}(1))$, we get $c_t(\mathcal{E}) = c_t(l)c_t(f) = (1+(l-1)t)c_t(f)$. Hence $a_1(\mathcal{E})$ should be $l-1$ but this is clearly not in $K(X)$ (linearly independent with $1$ over $K(X)$), also not in $GK(X)$ similarly.
After some googling, I noticed that $\sum e^{a_i(\mathcal{E})} = \sum_{m=0}^\infty [1/m!\sum_{i=1}^r a_i(\mathcal{E})^m] = m + c_1(\mathcal{E}) + \frac{1}{2!}(c_1(\mathcal{E})^2-2c_2(\mathcal{E}))+\cdots.$ If we define $ch(\mathcal{E})$ by RHS then we don't need $a_i(\mathcal{E})$ so maybe I should take this as the definition. Second question: does this prove that $e^{l-1}\in GK(X)$? Third question: why this lies in $GK(X)\otimes \mathbb{Q}$, not $GK(X)\otimes \mathbb{R}$? Although grading in $GK$ is finite (for regular $X$ with ample line bundle), each term in formula involves $c_1(\mathcal{E})$ and so on.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Now I think it doesn't make much sense to say values in $\mathbb{R}$ for this formal sum, but I still have no idea how to think infinite sum as an element.

OK I clarified some confusions.
